# Embed JFreeChart into Java Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jfreechart

Is there any way that I could embed `JFreeChart` into Java Servlet with the ability to have chart's crosshair, zoom in-out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you could get a `JFreeChart` into a web page is with an Applet. You can't do this with a servlet alone.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use [java-web-start](/questions/tagged/java-web-start) to launch an application from the web page.